# Current time of Universe and reincarnation

Tags: gods, time

There is no possibility to synchronize time of whole universe.

Now question is- how super soul/nature synchronize the time of universe and follow reincarnation theory if it is true?

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  It isn't clear what you're asking.  What does synchronizing time across the Universe have to do with reincarnation?

Comment: There's no need to synchronize time. Each plane has it's own time and it has nothing to do with reincarnation.